# Coping with remote host's outdated /usr/bin/git

Tags: git

The "default" `git` on Centos host `BADHOST`, namely `/usr/bin/git`, is ancient (v 1.7.1), much older in fact than all the other instances of `git` I work with.

As it turns out, said host `BADHOST` has a more recent version (2.5.0) of `git` installed in a non-standard location (`/opt/git-2.5.0/bin/git`).  This is the version I use when I'm logged into `BADHOST`, and therefore, my `$HOME/.gitconfig` file on `BADHOST` is written to work with `/opt/git-2.5.0/bin/git`.

In fact, `BADHOST`'s default `git` (`/usr/bin/git`) regards my `$HOME/.gitconfig` as *invalid*:

```
error: Malformed value for push.default: simple
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.
fatal: bad config file line 10 in /home/yourstruly/.gitconfig
```

This becomes a problem whenever I try to perform a `git` operation having `BADHOST` as the remote host.  Most such operations fail with errors similar to the one shown above.

For example, if I'm logged into some other host (`OKHOST`), the command

```
git clone BADHOST:/path/to/some/git/repo
```

...fails with

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: error: Malformed value for push.default: simple
remote: error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.
remote: fatal: bad config file line 10 in /home/yourstruly/.gitconfig
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

If, however, I delete `$HOME/.gitconfig` on `BADHOST`, and then re-run the `git clone` command on `OKHOST`, it succeeds.

Is there a way around this crazy problem?

**NB:** I'm looking for solutions *other than* changing my `$HOME/.gitconfig` file on `BADHOST` so that it is acceptable to its outdated `/usr/bin/git`, but no longer works appropriately with `/opt/git-2.5.0/bin/git`.  Also, the `BADHOST`'s sysadmin has denied all my requests to have `/usr/bin/git` upgraded, so solutions predicated on such an upgrade are also of no interest.

In case it matters, my shell on `BADHOST` is `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: How do you run the newer `git` when logged in? Do you have `/opt/git-2.5.0/bin` in your path, or are you running it "manually" (via an alias, for example)?

Comment: @chepner: it's in my `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution.  Basically I created two scripts: `twit` and `ssh-wrapper`.

`twit` is very simple: it just calls `git` with `GIT_SSH` set to point to `ssh-wrapper`.

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT_SSH=/path/to/ssh-wrapper git "$@"
```

`ssh-wrapper` is trickier (more likely to need further work).  It assumes that its first argument will be a host name, and its second argument a command, beginning with the name of a "`git`-related" executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

host=$1
cmd=/opt/git-2.5.0/bin/$2

exec ssh "$host" "$cmd"
```

Now, commands like, for example,

```
twit clone BADHOST:/path/to/some/git/repo
twit push  BADHOST:/path/to/some/git/repo master
twit pull  BADHOST:/path/to/some/git/repo master
```

...succeed.

An ugly hack, to be sure.  I'm definitely open to better solutions.